# Javascript alert is prompting twice in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a file validation for uploading only `xls` files. But if I am uploading files other than excel, than its prompting the error properly.

But the issue is the `alert` is firing twice in `IE`

Below is my code.

```
function isFileValid() {
        var allowedFiles = [".xlsx", ".xls"];
        var fileUpload = document.getElementById("MainContent_fluploadData");
        var regex = new RegExp("([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(" + allowedFiles.join('|') + ")$");

        if (!regex.test(fileUpload.value.toLowerCase())) {                
            alert("Please upload files having extensions: " + allowedFiles.join(', ') + " only.");               
            $('#MainContent_fluploadData').val('');
            return false;
        }            
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="fluploadData" Style="padding-top: 0px; padding-left: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-right: 0px;" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" onchange="return isFileValid();" />
```

**NOTE**

I am using the file upload control inside update panel

Comment: when you reset fileupload element with this `$('#MainContent_fluploadData').val('');` you trigger again the "onChange" event

Comment: @Jabberwocky: not getting it mate.  you mean to say both things at the start and end of the function ?

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio: yes, i think so. any suggestion ?

Comment: Echoing what @GrafiCodeStudio said. This is a known difference between IE and other browsers - they implement the onchange spec differently and IE fires the event when the input field is changed programatically, whereas other browsers don't.  Example of this same bug causing issues - https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/8793

Comment: @JoshuaT: So, is this a bug of `IE 11` ?

Comment: Not exactly a bug, but just irregular considering how other browsers handle it (and in this case, introducing bugs onto various platforms because of it). In your scenario, I would recommend just doing something like holding a variable that persists outside of that function, like "lastCheckedFilename" and then in the onchange event handler, check if the user has actually changed the selected file by comparing the new filename to the lastCheckedFilename, and only alert if they are different.

Comment: @JoshuaT: good one, if you put in code that would be greater. :)

Comment: Sure - in your case, I actually overcomplicated things - you can simply check if the filename has been reverted by your own code (set back to "") before alerting again - should be as simple as changing `if (!regex.test(fileUpload.value.toLowerCase()))` to `if (!regex.test(fileUpload.value.toLowerCase()) && fileUpload.value!=='')`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193637/discussion-between-b-n-and-joshua-t).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To summarize the conclusion reached in the comments and the solution; this bug is caused by a difference in how IE handles onchange events for input elements, vs other browsers. For IE, when you change the value of a file input element programatically, like you are doing  with `$('#MainContent_fluploadData').val('');`, it actually causes *another* onchange event to be emitted, whereas it does not in other browsers. Most other browser do not re-emit the onchange event in this scenario.

The easiest solution in this scenario is to just add a check to see if your own code has already reverted the input field back to "" (no file selected), by modifying your IF statement from:

```
if (!regex.test(fileUpload.value.toLowerCase()))
```

to:

```
if (!regex.test(fileUpload.value.toLowerCase()) && fileUpload.value!=='')
```

---

If you start doing something like reverting to the last value instead of to an empty string (unselected file), you would want to do something like hold the value of the last checked filename as a variable outside that function, then check it against the new filename to see if the file selection has actually changed.

---

For more info:

- https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/8793
- http://jsfiddle.net/lmeurs/2rEzF/